# getting error 'No appenders are available for AsyncAppender ASYNC' while log4j 1.x to 2.x migration

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I am getting error 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationException: No appenders are available for AsyncAppender ASYNC' while migrating from log4j1.x to log4j 2.x using the Log4j 1.x bridge as per https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html.

I have tried to add 'CONSOLE' appender in appender-ref of 'ASYNC' appender but it didnt work for me.(reference : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-894)

Complete stack trace :

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationException: No appenders are available for AsyncAppender ASYNC
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AsyncAppender.start(AsyncAppender.java:117)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:255)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:530)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:603)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:620)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:226)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:152)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:307)
        at org.apache.log4j.LogManager$PrivateManager.getContext(LogManager.java:215)
        at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:74)
        at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:73)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:277)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:155)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:657)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.(AbstractApplicationContext.java:159)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.(AbstractApplicationContext.java:223)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:88)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.(AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.java:58)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:61)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:136)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
        at com.sm.common.business.security.StrongMailSymmetricEncryptionUtility.(StrongMailSymmetricEncryptionUtility.java:53)

**My log4j2.xml **:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
  <Appenders>
    <Async name="ASYNC">
      <AppenderRef ref="R"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </Async>
   <Async name="ASYNC_WARN">
     <ThresholdFilter level="WARN"/>
     <AppenderRef ref="R"/>
     <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE"/>
   </Async
    <Console name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p [%t] %C{2} - %m%n"/>
    </Console>   
 </Appenders>

 <Loggers>    
    <Logger name="com.sm" level="WARN" additivity="false">
      <AppenderRef ref="ASYNC"/>
    </Logger> 
    <Logger name="com.sm.random" level="WARN" additivity="false">
      <AppenderRef ref="ASYNC_WARN"/>
    </Logger> 
    <Logger name="com.sm.services" level="WARN" additivity="false">
      <AppenderRef ref="ASYNC"/>
    </Logger>

    <Root level="WARN">
      <AppenderRef ref="ASYNC"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please show your Log4j2 configuration.

Comment: edited question to include Log4j2 configuration

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it was happening due to the log directory access permission was denied

Comment: I was using it in AWS lambda. My log directory configuration was set to /opt while in lambda we only have write permission to /tmp. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 2):

There could be multiple reason this exception occurs. Below are some:

1) There are duplicate log4j configuration in the project or inside the dependent jar you are using

2) No appenders added in log4j file

3) If appenders are added correctly then two or more log4j configuration are clashing.

In my case, this was happening due to two log4j2.xml file was configured.

Answer (score 1):

The `<Async name="ASYNC">...` appender should be defined *after* the Appenders that it references. For example, the console appender is defined after the Async appender; it should be before.

Also, the Async appender has a `<AppenderRef ref="R"/>` that refers to a non-existing appender with name R. You need to either remove this AppenderRef or define the appender.

Comment: This helped me . Thanks!